# Issue to float an image to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something [like thi](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/RXrvZ/1/)s but for some reason float right doesn't seem to be working in my case (picture is place below the text area, not next to it). See JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YJ2p9/
What is wrong? Thanks

```
<div class="element element-2"> 

  <h4>Overview</h4>
                    <div class="post-content"><p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer</p> <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer</p> <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer</p></div><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-250-200-1.jpg" width="300" height="250">
                </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.element {

  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.element-2 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}


.post-thumb {
    float: right;
}
.post-thumb img {
    display: block
}
.post-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: maybe swapping the 2 divs in your HTML code results in what you want http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YJ2p9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/bd7Jy/3/

the image wanted to be inside the `'post-content'` div.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish for the image on the left like your example: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ2p9/7/

```
.element {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    width: 100%;
}    

.post-thumb {
    float: left
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -calc(100% - 300px);
}
.post-content {
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**change in HTML**

```
<div class="element element-2"> 

  <h4>Overview</h4>
                    <div class="post-content"><p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer</p> <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer</p> <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer</p></div><div class="post-thumb"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-250-200-1.jpg" width="300" height="250">
                </div>

    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

**and in css**

```
.element {

  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.element-2 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}


.post-thumb {
    float: right;
}
.post-thumb img {
    display: block
}
.post-content {
   margin-left: 10px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
```

**no need to put  image div (post-thumb) inside 'post-content'**